# Cannot bind trigger click on svg path element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I cannot simmulate click on svg path element. But other actions like remove() are working.

I have this and it does not work:

```
$("#parentelement").on("click", "someelement", function() {
      $('g path[data-code="' + something + '"].jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element').trigger("click");
 });
```

not working also with ....`click()`;

But it works with `.remove()` or `.trigger("remove")`;

Any ideas or help? Thanx!

Comment: `$('g path[data-code="' + something + '"].jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element')[0].click()`

Comment: Does not work :/ undefined is not a function

Comment: Can you provide some JSFiddle? It's not really clear how your HTML looks like and what you're exactly doing. Also, why do you want to trigger a click event while clicking an some other element?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly bind jQuery events with SVG, but there is a library to do so.

Check it out here:
[jQuery SVG Integration](https://github.com/kbwood/svg)

Comment: Normal/vanilla jQuery is intended to work with HTML elements only.  Some of the functions will work with SVG also, but that's accidental.

Comment: Also basically jQuery .remove() just remove the associated element, there is no event handler attached for this. But click or focus etc. event handlers just won't work without a bridge b/w them.